# In android studio is there a way to disable a module without deleting it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have several modules in a project in android studio. Sometimes when there are compiler errors etc I want to disable other modules so that only certain modules are compiled for example I want to only focus on independent libraries etc and want their dependent modules to be unloaded/not included in the compile etc.

How can I do that ? I know there is a way to delete them but I don't want them deleted. Just like in visual studio or eclipse we could unload certain projects in a work space.

Comment: simply remove from your gradel file to remove the module from your project

Comment: in the `settings.gradle` file all modules which should be loaded are defined. if you remove the module from this list, it does not get compiled and it does not get deleted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in order to disable the module you should follow these steps

- in the  settings.gradle remove the library from include
- also remove the using of it from build.gradle